# Яке значення має слова "веснуємо"?

Tags: значення-слів

Наткнулась в Facebook на рекламу [Парковий квартал "Місто квітів"](https://www.facebook.com/MistoKvitiv/videos/599412790400162/)

***Що саме в рекламі означає слово "веснуємо"?***

В СУМ знайшла значення слова [Веснувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vesnuvaty)- Виконувати весняні роботи.

***Веснуємо***, тобто виконуємо веснянні роботи (посадка рослин, догляд за садом)?

Comment: Мабуть, вони мали на увазі щось на зразок «насолоджуємося весною». Хоча саме такого значення в словниках нема, але є «проводити [десь] весну», як [Oksana Çeliker зазначила у відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3383), а сам контекст передбачає приємні емоції.

Answer (score 1):

Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)

> Проводить весну́ – веснува́ти десь.

Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)

> Проводить весну где – [Весну] веснувати десь. [Де ти будеш цю весну веснувати? З нар. уст.]

Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)

> Веснува́ти – проводить весну.

Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)

> Встрѣча́ть, провожа́ть весну́ = веснува́ти.

СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE

> ВЕСНУВА́ТИ, у́ю, у́єш, недок.
>
> 1. Виконувати весняні роботи. – Чи здорово коло вас, ґаздине Марто? Та й як веснуєте? Давно вас не бачили (О. Кобилянська); – Добрий день!
>      Ой, ой, як ви, Параско, вийшли рано веснувати.., – посміхувався Микола
>      Скрип, вітаючись (І. Чендей); Польовими дорогами там і там торохтять,
>      вискрипують вози, куряву здіймаючи, форкають в упряжі гладкі коні –
>      їдуть люди в поле веснувати (І. Нижник).
> 2. перев. з обставиною місця. Проводити де-небудь весну; жити у весняну пору в певному місці. Нам теж треба поспішати додому, бо
>      незабаром ріки розіллються так, що й веснувати доведеться біля Дубна
>      (В. Малик); Чоловік Насті виїхав у перший день війни, а вона лишилася,
>      бо після пологів була. Жила в людей по хатах, а тоді покрила соломою
>      каплицю біля костьолу і якось веснувала в ній (М. Малиновська);
>      “Сміливий” – та це ж містечко Сміла, куди вони поїхали веснувати й
>      літувати! (Ю. Хорунжий).

Наведений контекст - реклама послуг з перетворення ландшафту? Тоді не виключено перше значення - "виконання весняних робіт". Якщо же це запрошення на якийсь захід, за відсутності обставини місця, найбільш підходить значення "зустрічати весну".